# Access 2003 Query Dilemma

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am, having difficulty with multiple values returning for each user. I have tried variations of Select Distinct to no avail.  I need my code to only retun one value per userID.

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, 
    EventLog.Type, 
    IIf([EventLog]![LogType] Like "Acc*" And [EventLog]![Action] Like "Wri*",[EventLog]![Date],Date()-183) AS [Review Date]
FROM EventLog 
INNER JOIN Roster 
    ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, 
    EventLog.Type, 
    IIf([EventLog]![LogType] Like "Acc*" And [EventLog]![Action] Like "Wri*",[EventLog]![Date],Date()-183)
HAVING (((EventLog.Type) Like "Att*"));
```

The code is returning both values from the IIf when they meet the first criteria.  How can I limit to one or the other?

Comment: Please remove the chat and add more code.

Comment: Sorry Folks new to this.  I have removed the novel and cleaned up the post.

Comment: Hard to tell without the tables structures and some sample data. Can you provide an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting multiple values per user because you've listed multiple fields in your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
    GROUP BY Roster.UserID, 
        EventLog.Type, 
        IIf([EventLog]![LogType] Like "Acc*" And 
[EventLog]![Action] Like "Wri*",[EventLog]![Date],Date()-183)
```

I'm not sure why you're grouping at all, as you're not performing any aggregate functions.  Would `SELECT DISTINCT` work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback folks.  Basedon what Beth replied and cleaning up my tables and querys to send a copy of the dBasethe problem seemed to work itself out with a small addition of code.

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, 
EventLog.Type, 
Max(IIf(EventLog!LogType Like "Acc*" And EventLog!Action Like "Wri*",EventLog!Date,Date()-183)) AS [Review Date]
FROM EventLog 
INNER JOIN Roster 
ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID,
EventLog.Type
HAVING (((EventLog.Type) Like "Att*"));
```

The clean up of the multi fields from Beth worked a treat!!!